# How do I create an AppDomain with a null evidence?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

When you instantiate a .NET class via COM, the [evidence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.evidence(v=vs.110).aspx) of the created AppDomain [is null](http://rekiwi.blogspot.co.at/2008/12/unable-to-determine-identity-of-domain.html).

I am trying to analyze a problem that only occurs when the AppDomain evidence is null, and I'd like to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) purely in .NET, i.e., without having to register the class in COM and call it from there. For that, I need an AppDomain with an empty evidence.

How would I do that? When passing `null` to [AppDomain.CreateDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dba63a0(v=vs.110).aspx), the evidence of the current AppDomain is reused.

Comment: Checking the source code of the Evidence property of AppDomain class, there seems to be no way that the Evidence of any AppDomain to be null. Are you sure that the Evidence of the AppDomain created by instantiating a .net class via COM is null? Can you please check the answer of mine (just to put the Evidence property source code, not a real answer)

Comment: What version of .net framework it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truly, there is no way of creating an AppDomain with a null evidence in .Net 4.0 +. Is your code running on an earlier version?

The `AppDomain.Evidence` property returns the internal `AppDomain.EvidenceNoDemand` property and the decompiled source code for both getters are below,

It seems from the source code that no app domain can ever have a null evidence, no matter it' is created via COM or via a managed assembly.

```
public Evidence Evidence
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries"), SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlEvidence=true)]
    get
    {
        return this.EvidenceNoDemand;
    }
}

internal Evidence EvidenceNoDemand
{
    [SecurityCritical]
    get
    {
        if (this._SecurityIdentity != null)
        {
            return this._SecurityIdentity.Clone();
        }
        if (!this.IsDefaultAppDomain() && this.nIsDefaultAppDomainForEvidence())
        {
            return GetDefaultDomain().Evidence;
        }
        return new Evidence(new AppDomainEvidenceFactory(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are entirely correct, I was mistaken in my assumption that the evidence is null. In fact, the evidence is empty (Count = 0), which is, of course, something different. Thanks for your help!